# How to timed events work?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm working on an app and I'd like to program timed activities. For example, if you've played games like 'The Simpsons: Tapped Out', 'Clash of Clans', 'Sim City: Build It' and many others, you'll know the user can set up an activity (eg, build a house/set the character to complete a task) and return later to find it complete or, at least advanced. For instance, a character initiated on a 24 hour task is, 8 hours later, 16 hours short of completion.

How does this work? Is the timing linked to the cloud timers? Or is it linked to the phones own time processing? What is this side of programming called? Is 'timed activity' the correct terminology?

Please help, I'm very confused.I must admit, I am very much an amateur.

Thanks
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you could use the **AlarmManager**. Its used for calling a **BroadcastReceiver** at a specified time. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/) for example, but there are many other tutorials about this topic on the internet.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm sorry I've taken ages to respond. Since taking you suggestions, I've been investigating further. I found something called timestamps. Do you think they'd work?